# Can't connect to mongoDB with node.js using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the code which I've written:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const userSchema = require('./userSchema.js')
const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema, 'user')

async function createUser(username) {
    return new User({
        username,
        created: Date.now()
    }).save()
}

async function findUser(username) {
    return await User.findOne({
        username
    })
}

;
(async() => {
    const connector = mongoose.connect(connectionString)
    const username = process.argv[2].split('=')[1]

    let user = await connector.then(async() => {
        return findUser(username)
    }).catch(console.log("Error found"))

    if (!user) {
        user = await createUser(username)
    }

    console.log(user)
    process.exit(0)
})()
```

But the following error is coming. i couldn't figure out what is going wrong. Any idea?

[code error snippet here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPijX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Then `nodemon` or `node app.js` to start server.

Comment: Since i'm using windows, i've used CMD in Run as administrator mode. Still didn't worked.

Comment: It may take 2-3 min. after a fire, this command then tries to run a server.

Comment: Mongodb is running fine in local system. I've executed multiple commands. Shall i still reinstall it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your connection string. You can obtain the connection string from Mongo atlas.

1. https://developerhandbook.com/mongodb/connect-mongo-atlas-mongoose/

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the connection string. Is there any way to check it?

Comment: Did you whitelist your IP?

Comment: Yes. I've whitelisted the IP address. I'm currently using my mobile hotspot data. It shouldn't make much difference :/

Comment: Did you created the db user?

Comment: Yes i did. The Connection String contains username and password too.

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();


// Connecting to the database
mongoose.connect('mongodb:uri',{ useNewUrlParser: true } ).then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...');
    process.exit();
});
```